# Powershell set password for local user

Tags: powershell

Is there an easy way to set a password for a local user when the user doesn't have a password yet? I searched for it but couldn't find anything that worked. The following is what I found:

```bsh
$password="password"
$UserAccount = Get-LocalUser -Name "nameofuser"
$UserAccount | Set-LocalUser -Password $password
```

The computers I am trying to give a password are not in a domain.

Comment: Please expand on what "didn't work" - are you getting any errors? If so, what does the error message say?

Comment: please `Read The Friendly Manual`. [*grin*] this ... `Get-Help Set-LocalUser -Parameter Password` ... makes the reason your code fails painfully obvious.

Comment: When you start your computer does ask for a password to log in?

Comment: No it only gives me a button to sign in or logs me in automatically.